# Using phantomjs with Chrome API and Emulation in view in console

Tags: google-chrome, phantomjs, google-chrome-app

I could find answer but I was wondering if there is a way to pass to chrome by command line and using phantomjs additional stuff connected with new feature in chrome settings - overrides 'Show emulation view in console drawer'.

I want to do screenshoot in chrome and devices that are defined Sources/Emulation...

Cheers for help.

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I'm not sure to understand what you want to achieve or if it's even related to Chrome Apps.